# Type Error related to POST data should be bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, typeerror

**So, I have " POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str." error on my screen**.

```
 import urllib.request, json

  req = urllib.request.Request('Website API Address')

req.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer {Key}')

data = json.dumps({
  "emails": [
    "snriedel85@gmail.com"
  ]

})
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req,data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `ascii` encoding:

```py
import urllib.request, json

data = json.dumps({"emails": ["snriedel85@gmail.com"]})
data = data.encode('ascii') # data should be bytes

req = urllib.request.Request('Website API Address', data)
req.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer {Key}')

response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

If that won't work I recommend to read this [HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#data).

Comment: Now it says 
HTTPError: Bad Request

Comment: Check your URL and headers. Maybe you forgot to add `f` before `f'Bearer {Key}'`?